# How to stop NSExpression from rounding

Tags: swift3, nsexpression

I've been making a calculator in Swift 3, but have run into some problems.

I have been using **NSExpression** to calculate the users equation, but the answer is always rounded.

To check that the answer was rounded, I calculated **3 / 2**.

```
let expression = NSExpression(format: "3 / 2");
let answer: Double = expression.expressionValue(with: nil, context: nil) as! Double;
Swift.print(String(answer));
```

The above code outputs **1.0**, instead of **1.5**.

Does anyone know how to stop NSExpression from rounding? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression is using integer division since your operands are integers. Try this instead:

```
let expression = NSExpression(format: "3.0 / 2.0");
let answer: Double = expression.expressionValue(with: nil, context: nil) as! Double;
Swift.print(String(answer));
```

Consider the following code:

```
let answer = Double(3 / 2)
```

`answer` in this case would still be `1.0` since `3 / 2` is evaluated to `1` before being inserted in the `Double` initializer.

However, this code would give `answer` the value of `1.5`:

```
let answer = Double(3.0 / 2.0)
```

This is because `3.0 / 2.0` will be evaluated based on the division operation for `Double` instead of the division operation of `Integer`.

Comment: Thanks for the help